# Autowire not working in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, autowired

I have the following class:

```
public class Triangle implements Shape {
    /*@Autowired
     @Qualifier("A")*/

    private Point A;
    /*@Autowired
     @Qualifier("B")*/
    private Point B;
    /*@Autowired
     @Qualifier("C")*/
    private Point C;

    private static AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();

    private int ownId;
    private int beanAttribute;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int secondaryId;
    private String constructor = "Simple type --";

    private static final String NAME = "triangle";

    Triangle() {
        System.out.println("Triangle created without a secondaryId \n");
        secondaryId = -1;

    }

    Triangle(int secondaryId) {
        this.secondaryId = secondaryId;
        this.ownId = id.addAndGet(1);
    }

    Triangle(int secondaryId, String constructor) {
        this.secondaryId = secondaryId;
        this.ownId = id.addAndGet(1);
        this.constructor = constructor;
    }

    public Point getA() {
        return A;
    }

    public void setA(Point a) {
        A = a;
    }

    public Point getB() {
        return B;
    }

    public void setB(Point b) {
        B = b;
    }

    public Point getC() {
        return C;
    }

    public void setC(Point c) {
        C = c;
    }

    public int getOwnId() {
        return ownId;
    }
}
```

With the following XML config:

```
<beans>
<bean id="triangleDouble" class="draw.Triangle"
     scope="prototype" autowire="byName">
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="Double type ++" />
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="0" />
    <property name="beanAttribute" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean id="triangleSimple" class="draw.Triangle"
 scope="prototype" autowire="byName">
    <constructor-arg value="1" />
    <property name="beanAttribute" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="A" class="draw.Point">
    <property name="x" value="1" />
    <property name="y" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean id="B" class="draw.Point">
    <property name="x" value="2" />
    <property name="y" value="3" />
</bean>

<bean id="C" class="draw.Point">
    <property name="x" value="3" />
    <property name="y" value="4" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

The problem is that Autowiring is not working. If I set `<property name="A" ref="A"/>` etc, there will be no NullPointerException and I can access Point.x or Point.y, so the code is written correctly, but if I autowire byName, the autowiring will not work and when I will try to access Point.x from Triangle I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I tried to set the class members A,B,C with `@Autowire`, both with `@Autowire` and `@Qualifier("A")` and with no Annotation at all, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code sample has annotations commented out, is this what you tried? Have you tried without `/*` around the annotations `*/`

Comment: Yes, I tried all the combinations:only with @ Autowired, only with @ Qualifier, both with @ Autowired and @ Qualifier and without any of the annotations.

Comment: Show us more code; a small program that reproduces the problem. Currently there is not enough information in your question to tell what's wrong.

Comment: please show your entire xml config file. I wonder if you have declared the following tag : <context:annotation-config />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your Point bean names to lower-case and add setters like 'setA()', 'setB' etc. to the Triangle class. It will solve the problem.

The trouble is that you did not follow the JavaBeans convention.

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error after running your program:

> Bean property 'beanAttribute' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="triangleDouble" bean id="triangleDouble" class="draw.Triangle"
         scope="prototype" autowire="byName">
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="Double type ++" />
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="0" />
        <property name="beanAttribute" value="2" />
</bean>
```

You have missed setter method for beanAttribute.Add the same and it should work.

For more info refer [setter-injection](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-basic-setter-injection.html)

Comment: I did not get this error. The answer is that my variables were named A,B,C and the setters were getA, getB, getC but somehow Spring could not recognize them. After renaming them with pointA, pointB, pointC and having the getPointA, setPointA etc getters/setters, it works. The solution is from @Alexander

Comment: It should work even if you use variable name as A,B and C. What ever I posted is the Tested code in my System. More over in your question you have mentioned autowire does not work. In your xml file did you put <context:annotation-config /> before?

Comment: No, i did not. Still, it works if I change the name of the variables to point[A-C] and gives me a nullPointerException if I have them with A,B,C.

Comment: Here is the full remade test project that works with point[A-C] but not [A-C]: https://gist.github.com/alexandruantochi/e6d5d19b970ae018f1a53a78aa150257

Comment: Could you un comment those (Autowire annotation), add <context:annotation-config /> in xml, add setter for beanAttribute. Run with your old program? If it does not work I will try to share it in git hub.

Comment: There is a lot of difference between the code which you have posted and the one in GIT HUB.

Comment: I just rewrote it because the other one was more complicated and I had to extract parts of it for the question. This one is exactly on point.

Comment: I have answered the question based on what you have posted.